# Why are the CRM function definitions different for me than the codes I see online?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

*I apologize for my vague question title*

I found a code online that suggests a way to create a `queryexpression` as follows:

```
 QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression(entity1Name)
    {
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(false)
    };
```

When I tried to do the same in my code, I got an error that the :
**no constructor exists for QueryExpression that takes 1 argument.**
However, I can create my queryexpression using this way:

```
       QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
        query.EntityName=entity1Name;
        ColumnSet cset = new ColumnSet();
        cset.AllColumns = false;
```

This is just an example of many other CRM objects that also behave differently on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QueryExpression` class is defined inside the namespace `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query` (from `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll`) and it has 2 constructors:

```
public QueryExpression();
public QueryExpression(string entityName);
```

if you got an error probably you are not referencing the dll included inside the [CRM 2011 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004)